Start Powershell Maximized Thought Windows Terminal
Short Description:  If pwsh/powershell is not running  Maximized, re-open it Maximized
I have installed pwsh and wt, with pwsh as the default console in wt, and in some scripts, I want wt to run Maximized (wt doesn't run in Maximized by default. I don't want to set it).
In this .ps1, what code is needed to determine if wt is not running fullscreen/maximized, re-opening it in Maximized if it's not?
# demo.ps1
#$IsMax =
If (!$IsMax) {
    wt.exe -M PWSH $PSCommandPath; exit 0
} 
pause


Just a note, but excessive and uncommon acronyms may impact the ability of others to clearly and quickly understand what you're saying. What research have you done regarding maximizing console window size in PowerShell, or detecting current window size in PowerShell?

Get The Processes via Get-CimInstance, filter WindowsTerminal.exe, select the CommandLine property. if it's not -FullScreen or -F, restart the process with the correct parameter

You can for example:

get the parent Windows Terminal process of the PowerShell script:

(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $PID").ParentProcessId

Or simplier:
(Get-Process -Id $PID).Parent.Id

if you run as admin.

check if it the process with that ID is fullscreen. There's no easy way to do so as PS APIs are lacking such data, but a workaround could be to check CommandLine property of the process to check if it was launched in fullscreen with -F/-FullScreen. That of course won't consider the case of you switching to/from fullscreen with a keyboard shortcut or in any non-CLI way.

relaunch Windows Terminal in fullscreen with whatever you'd like to run, e.g.:


wt -F -d "$(pwd)" somescript.ps1

where -F is the arg for fullscreen.
Considering the 2nd bullet point, I don't think it's worth going for a fully optimal solution just to save a few seconds every now and then. I'd recommend always relaunching in fullscreen instead.

To have Windows Terminal launch in full-screen mode :

Enter Settings, section Startup
Open branch "Launch parameters"
Change "Launch mode" to "Full screen".

Note that pressing F11 in Terminal will switch between the
full screen and normal modes.

Thanks. But i do'nt want to set fullscreen by default. I only need auto fullscreen for some script.

You could use F11 - an easy method available when you need it.

Use F11 easy, but it's manually, not auto.

You should define better the problem- it's unclear to me when exactly you wish it full screen. You could perhaps create a desktop shortcut that will invoke it in this mode.

After googling and doing some testing, I finally found what I wanted.
If WT isn't maximized, then restart it maximized
Based on: Determine Size of PowerShell Console
To check whether it's maximized or not, by looking for $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width
$IsWTRun = 'WindowsTerminal' -in (Get-Process).Name
# WindowSize.Width while Maximized: WT=95, NotWT=103 (in my PC)
If ($IsWTRun) {$WID = 95} else {$WID = 103}
$IsMax = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width -eq $WID
if ( $IsMax ) {'in M.A.X.I.M.I.Z.E.D'; pause; exit 0}

$PS7 = $Host.Version.Major -eq 7
if ( $PS7 ) {wt.exe -M PWSH $PSCommandPath; exit 0}
$AL = "-M -d `"$PSScriptRoot`" -p `"Windows PowerShell`"",
      "PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`""
start wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL ; exit 0

Thanks for everyone who helped by answer or comment
